# Initialize Dictionary<string, List<string>>

Tags: c#, dictionary

I would like to know how do I declare/initialize a dictionary ?
The below one gives error.

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> myD = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>()
{
  {"tab1", MyList }
};

List <string> MyList = new List<string>() { "1" };
```

The error is: A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property MyList.  It is not List declaration coming in front or later after dictionary.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14472283/922198

Comment: "Gives an error". Cool. Care to share the error? :/

Comment: If those are instance fields, it cannot be done with a field initializers alone. You must initialize the dictionary in the constructor.

Comment: Thank you. initialized the dictionary as part of the constructor.

Comment: @mikez if `MyList` is only used as part of the dictionary and never has to be referenced directly, they could instead initialize a new list within the dictionary field initializer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Scott Chamberlain said in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472245/initialize-dictionarystring-liststring/14472392#14472392):

> If these are non static field definitions you can not use the field
>   initializers like that, you must put the data in the constructor.
>
> ```
> class MyClass
> {
>     Dictionary<string, List<string>> myD;        
>     List <string> MyList;
>
>     public MyClass()
>     {
>         MyList = new List<string>() { "1" };
>         myD = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>()
>         {
>           {"tab1", MyList }
>         };
>     }
> }
> ```

Additionally for Static field

```
private static List<string> MyList = new List<string>()
{    
   "1"
};

private static Dictionary<string, List<string>> myD = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>()
{
    {"tab1", MyList }

};
```

Comment: @SimonWhitehead - fixed thnx!

Answer (score 17):

```cs
class MyClass
{
    Dictionary<string, List<string>> myD = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>()
    {
        {"tab1", new List<string> { "1" } },
        {"tab2", new List<string> { "1","2","3" } },
        {"tab3", new List<string> { "one","two" } }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If these are non static field definitions you can not use the field initializers like that, you must put the data in the constructor.

```
class MyClass
{
    Dictionary<string, List<string>> myD;        
    List <string> MyList;

    public MyClass()
    {
        MyList = new List<string>() { "1" };
        myD = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>()
        {
          {"tab1", MyList }
        };
    }
}
```